# how to register generics with a different number of type parameters using .Net C# dependency injection

Tags: .net, generics, dependency-injection, generic-type-argument, servicecollection

I have an interface that takes 2 generic type parameters and an implementation that only takes one.

How does one setup the dependency mapping in the DI container?

Given the psuedo code:

```cs
interface IDataStore<TEntity, TQuery> 
{
    TEntity GetById(string id);

    TEntity[] Query(TQuery query);
}

class MySqlQuery {}

class MySqlDataStore<TEntity> : IDataStore<TEntity, MySqlQuery> 
{
    TEntity GetById(string id);

    TEntity[] Query(SqlQuery query);
}

class DynamoDBQuery {}

class DynamoDBDataStore<TEntity> : IDataStore<TEntity, DynamoDBQuery> 
{
    TEntity GetById(string id);

    TEntity[] Query(DynamoDBQuery query);
}
```

The following compiles but failes to resolve at runtime because there are a differing amount of type arguments:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(typeof(IDataStore<,>), typeof(MySqlDataStore<>));
```

And given:

```cs
services.AddSingleton(typeof(TInterface), typeof(TImplementation));
```

there doesn't seem to be a factory method for TImplementation that gives access to TInterface, because if there was one could just construct the concrete type in the factory with (psuedo code):

```cs
services.AddSingleton(
    typeof(IDataStore<,MySqlQuery>), 
    (interfaceType, serviceProvider) => typeof(MySqlDataStore<>).MakeGenericType(interfaceType.GenericArguments[0]));
```

I know one option is to just scan all assemblies for all TEntity and constuct the interface to concrete type mappings on application startup so will probably go with that but wondered if anyone has any ideas on how to do the mapping on service resolution instead.

Comment: If trying to use a feature causes such problems, you're probably doing it wrong. Even a human wouldn't know whether to return a `SqlDataStore<>` or something else when asked for a `IDataStore<,>`. The very fact there's a separate `TDataStoreConfig` in .NET Core instead of configuration settings,  `IConfiguration` or a common interface makes things harder.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do the classes actually look like?

Comment: Yes I agree, generally if the solution is complex, it indicates there is a better solution to be found so if you have one I'm all ears.

There are multiple types of datastore (sql, nosql, different sql flavours etc).
Each datastore is queried in very different ways so they can't share a common interface for their query. 

So read TConfig as TQueryConfig and hopefully it should make more sense.
The TQueryConfig is modified per request (per datastore) at runtime so can't be read from file etc.

Comment: EF Core does all these things and all it needs is `AddDbContext`. Granted, inside AddDbContext you have an entire configuration method, but that method is provided at the time of registration and has access to Configuration and Services through its arguments. You could try something similar and either replace the config interface with a config lambda, or use a factory method

Comment: That said, .NET Core's DI doesn't allow passing arguments during injection the way other DI containers do, through attributes or parameter values. You *may* be able to do the same by injecting a factory service instead of `IDataStore<>` and have that factory service create the instance you want.

Comment: Thanks @PanagiotisKanavos. Our actual usecase is for 2 NoSQL datastores which have almost the same CRUD interface except for when they're queried. Hence the need for two very different query configuration objects to support the different syntax and propreties required. It means that for the other CRUD methods that are the same across the two stores, we don't hae to write bespoke code. I'll update the question to better show this.

That said, a generic factory would work perfectly, thanks.

Comment: That's the equivalent of the `UseMySQL` or `UseNpgSQl` calls in AddDbContext. What you describe as query configuration objects are called providers in EF Core. The entire hierarchy is inverted, allowing a single DbContext to act as a multi-entity repo, and a DbSet to act as a single-entity Repo

Comment: Do you want to register all data store combinations at the start? In that case the users of `IDataStore` have to specify the database they want, not just the entity. If you know which entities come from which database in advance you could use register an `IEntityDataStore<ConcreteEntity>` for each type that uses a different provider each time. You can use reflection to find which is which, eg through an attribute on the store, or by inspecting

Answer (score -1):

For anyone interested, this is the code to do the registration on startup

```cs
var entityTypes = entityAssemblies
    .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
    .Where(t => typeof(IEntity).IsAssignableFrom(t));

foreach (var entityType in entityTypes)
{
    var implementationType = typeof(SqlDataStore<>).MakeGenericType(entityType);
    var interfaceType = implementationType
        .GetInterfaces()
        .First(i => i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IDataStore<,>));

    services.AddSingleton(interfaceType, implementationType);
}
```